# Spring data: CONCAT are removing commas when used with TRANSLATE

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm trying to perform the following query:

```
SELECT p FROM Pessoa p WHERE TRANSLATE(UPPER(p.nome), 'ÂÁÀÄÃÊÉÈËÎÍÌÏÔÓÒÖÕÛÚÙÜÇ', 'AAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC') LIKE CONCAT('%',TRANSLATE(UPPER(?1), 'ÂÁÀÄÃÊÉÈËÎÍÌÏÔÓÒÖÕÛÚÙÜÇ', 'AAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC'),'%')
```

But i realize that hibernate is generating the following final SQL:

```
... where TRANSLATE(upper(pessoa0_.ds_nome), 'ÂÁÀÄÃÊÉÈËÎÍÌÏÔÓÒÖÕÛÚÙÜÇ', 'AAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC') like ('%'||TRANSLATE(upper(?)||'ÂÁÀÄÃÊÉÈËÎÍÌÏÔÓÒÖÕÛÚÙÜÇ'||'AAAAAEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUC')||'%')...
```

Note that the commas inside the TRANSLATE function were replaced by **||** which leads to an **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function translate(text) does not exist**

What am I doing wrong?

Spring: 4.3.4.RELEASE

Spring data: spring-data-jpa:1.10.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is not simply replacing commas. It is converting a JPQL (or possibly HQL) query int SQL. The double pipes `||` are a common SQL syntax for the JPQL `CONCAT` function.

If it doesn't work for your Postgres DB you are probably using the wrong dialect. Configure Hibernate to use the correct Dialect for your database.

[See for example this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm) for how to do that.